# HDPI, LDPI, MDPI

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout, hdpi, mdpi

Sorry. I have no idea about Android screen size HDPI, LDPI, MDPI. How can I check my flutter app in these screen size?

Comment: What do you mean by "check my flutter app in these screen size"?

Answer (score 1):

Create new android emulators with different pixel densities, and run the app on them.  I wouldn't worry about ldpi (.1% of devices).  The cutoffs are 160 dpi (mdpi), 240 dpi (hdpi), 320 dpi (xhdpi) and 480 (xxhdpi).

Generally this shouldn't be a problem as long as you specified all your sizes in dp rather than pixels.  The most likely thing to want to change is images, make sure that any non-vector image looks good at multiple resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

HDPI, LDPI, MDPI all refer to the pixel density of your display and not resolution of the device.

Generally when developing for multiple screen sizes you should focus more on viewport (say 360dp and 600dp as your breakpoints), then find or create new android virtual devices that match your viewport and then run your app on those devices.

Here are a few good links:

[Material IO Pixel Density](https://material.io/design/layout/pixel-density.html#pixel-density)

[Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities)

[Android Device List](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Android_smartphones)